# WSDL2Java Failure - Nested Content

Tags: xsd, cxf, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I am trying to generate java stubs from a large set of schemas (15k lines total) using Axis2 wsdl2java and have encountered a problem with the following complex type. Originally when running the tool on my schema files I received an nondescript error message, "unsupported content Simple Content !"  To find the cause of this error I downloaded and deployed the Axis2 project from source, found the error string and examined the element causing the problem.
I believe the source of the problem relates to nesting a complex type with simple content inside simple content.

I have two examples, **SequencedTextType, which fails**, and **OpenTextType, which succeeds**. Both types have content that are extensions of TextType. This should make it easier to spot the problem and provide an explaination.

The **failing** SequencedTextType:

```
<xs:element name="Reason" type="SequencedTextType" id="oagis-id-fa892eb1e28c46088bc50394c62a8655"/>

<xs:complexType name="SequencedTextType" id="oagis-id-51e010d7a1e24ebe89fcf58989fefd1b">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="TextType">
            <xs:attribute name="sequenceNumber" type="NumberType_B98233" id="oagis-id-39a5a53826024a65a2291f50d9feecd3"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="NumberType_B98233" id="oagis-id-d614ed8726ff482c9c5a8183d735d9ed">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The **passing** OpenTextType:

```
<xs:complexType name="OpenTextType" id="oagis-id-5840f7a57dd949ababcd1eb394b2840c">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="TextType">
            <xs:attribute name="typeCode" type="CodeType_1E7368" id="oagis-id-2780e69800934662a4782be31c2bacf6"
                          use="optional"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="CodeType_1E7368" id="oagis-id-d2f721a297684b538e7dbb88cf5526bc">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:token"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The **shared** TextType:

```
<xs:complexType name="TextType" id="oagis-id-d97b8cf6a26f408db148163485796d15">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="TextType_62S0B4"/>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="TextType_62S0B4" id="oagis-id-89be97039be04d6f9cfda107d75926b4">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute name="languageCode" type="clm56392A20081107_LanguageCodeContentType" id="oagis-id-c8d0c7094d7d4fbeb7e50fd20a17c1b3" use="optional"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="clm56392A20081107_LanguageCodeContentType" id="oagis-id-c5e8ac8c44894e54a147a870136da686">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:normalizedString"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The Axis2 method:

```
private void copyMetaInfoHierarchy(BeanWriterMetaInfoHolder metaInfHolder,
                                   QName baseTypeName,
                                   XmlSchema parentSchema)
        throws SchemaCompilationException {

    //... Code omitted for clarity

    // see whether this type is also extended from some other type first
    // if so proceed to set their parents as well.
    if (type instanceof XmlSchemaComplexType) {
        XmlSchemaComplexType complexType = (XmlSchemaComplexType) type;
        if (complexType.getContentModel() != null) {
            XmlSchemaContentModel content = complexType.getContentModel();
            if (content instanceof XmlSchemaComplexContent) {
                //continue recursion 
            } else if (content instanceof XmlSchemaSimpleContent) {
                /***** TextType throws error in this branch *****/ 
                throw new SchemaCompilationException(
                        SchemaCompilerMessages.getMessage("schema.unsupportedcontenterror", "Simple Content"));
            } else {
                throw new SchemaCompilationException(
                        SchemaCompilerMessages.getMessage("schema.unknowncontenterror"));
            }
        }
        //Do the actual parent setting
        metaInfHolder.setAsParent(baseMetaInfoHolder);
    }
    //... Code omitted for clarity
}
```

And here is the relevant error message:

> Caused by: org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompilationException: Unsupported content Simple Content !
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.copyMetaInfoHierarchy(SchemaCompiler.java:1396)
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexContent(SchemaCompiler.java:1279)
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processContentModel(SchemaCompiler.java:1228)
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexType(SchemaCompiler.java:1172)
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processNamedComplexSchemaType(SchemaCompiler.java:1092)
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processSchema(SchemaCompiler.java:1006)
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:772)
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:604)
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.process(SchemaCompiler.java:2052)
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processParticle(SchemaCompiler.java:1935)
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexContent(SchemaCompiler.java:1283)
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processContentModel(SchemaCompiler.java:1228)
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexType(SchemaCompiler.java:1172)
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processNamedComplexSchemaType(SchemaCompiler.java:1092)
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexContent(SchemaCompiler.java:1261)
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processContentModel(SchemaCompiler.java:1228)
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexType(SchemaCompiler.java:1172)
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processNamedComplexSchemaType(SchemaCompiler.java:1092)
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processSchema(SchemaCompiler.java:1006)
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:645)
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:615)
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.compile(SchemaCompiler.java:423)
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.compile(SchemaCompiler.java:292)
>   at org.apache.axis2.schema.ExtensionUtility.invoke(ExtensionUtility.java:102)

I am hoping for some insight into why OpenTextType can pass through the attached Axis2 method and why SequencedTextType cannot. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not really sure why it happens like that.
But, I found solution from [this link](http://www.javamonamour.org/2013/03/axis-161-or-flash-unsupported-content.html)

It worked for me when I add `-d xmlbeans` while using `wsdl2java` command

The default binding is adb and it has some issue with this Simple Content.
It seems this has been fixed in Axis2 1.7.x versions.